# adding DB name to a multiple database search - SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below SQL query that brings back a column on a particular table in all databases on the server that has this table in.

What I wanted to do was to include the database name on the results, however, as I have the `declare` I am not sure how to do it as I can't just put:

```
select  [DBName] = DB_Name(),
        user_id
    from DBO.sys_user
```

As it throws up a column name doesn't match table definition....does anyone have any ideas?

I also thought about putting in `PRINT ''DBName='' + DB_Name()` as well but haven't got anywhere with this...

```
declare @results table (
    user_id varchar(4)
);

insert @results
exec sp_msforeachdb N'
use [?]

IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = ''sys_user'')
begin
    select  
        user_id
    from DBO.sys_user
    
end;
';

select * from @results;
```

Comment: I'm not sure I follow what you are asking. What's wrong with what you have? What are the errors you are getting? Your table variable `@results` doesn't have a column defined for the database name, so if you try to `INSERT` 2 columns into it you *will* get an error.

Comment: You probably want to forget about using sp_msforeachdb, it's undocumented and bugged. Simply build your desired sql statements by querying `sys.databases` and `sys.tables/columns` and aggregating the results into a single statement.

Comment: @ThomA - this is what I am trying to achieve in having the database name as a column on this table so I know what database it relates to when looking at this table on multiple databases

Comment: @Stu - thanks for the input and looks like gotqqn is helping me on this in the answer section

Comment: Change your code to: declare @results table (db sysname, user_id varchar(4)) ... select db_name(), user_id from DBO.sys_users

Comment: @siggemannen - yep that works, thanks a lot!! Will also carry on looking into not using `sp_msforeachdb` as well as mentioned

Comment: [The sp_MSforeachdb procedure is an undocumented procedure that allows ....](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1414/run-same-command-on-all-sql-server-databases-without-cursors/#:~:text=The%20sp_MSforeachdb%20procedure%20is%20an%20undocumented%20procedure%20that%20allows)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [database] SYSNAME
   ,[user_id] BIGINT
);

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STRING_AGG(CAST('IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.[sys].[tables] WHERE [name] = ''sys_user'') INSERT INTO #DataSource ([database], [user_id]) SELECT DB_NAME(), user_id FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.[dbo].[sys_user]' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;

SELECT *
FROM #DataSource;
```

---

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #DataSource;

CREATE TABLE #DataSource
(
    [database] SYSNAME
   ,[user_id] BIGINT
);

DECLARE @DynamicTSQLStatement NVARCHAR(MAX);

SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STRING_AGG(CAST('BEGIN TRY IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.[sys].[tables] WHERE [name] = ''sys_user'') INSERT INTO #DataSource ([database], [user_id]) SELECT DB_NAME(), user_id FROM ' + QUOTENAME([name]) + '.[dbo].[sys_user] END TRY BEGIN CATCH END CATCH' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)), ';')
FROM sys.databases
WHERE state_desc = 'ONLINE'

EXEC sp_executesql @DynamicTSQLStatement;

SELECT *
FROM #DataSource;
```

Comment: I'm getting an `The server principal "****" is not able to access the database "****" under the current security context.` error on this...any ideas?

Comment: @PeterK Ut seems you have not access to all databases. Can you run the query with sys.admin for example?

Comment: I am not an SA....I thought your answer would only look in if it exists and wouldn't have to worry about restricted databases. This is what mine currently does and works as it is - is there a way to do the same with yours?

Comment: @PeterK as we are quiring sys.database you can add as many filters in the WHERE clause as you need.

Comment: I've tried updating yours to have `SELECT @DynamicTSQLStatement = STRING_AGG(CAST('IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.tables WHERE name = ''sys_user'')` which doesn't come up with any errors, but doesn't produce any data in the search results?

Comment: @PeterK In the where clause just add few databases to test.

Comment: @PeterK check the second query

Comment: Thank you for helping...I've tried the second query and no errors but still now results, just the column names. I've tried adding one database in but still getting the same issue

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/252662/discussion-between-gotqn-and-peterk).